# "Seams" in first layer

Tags: ultimaker-cura, anycubic-i3-mega, anycubic-ultrabase

My first layers started to have these "seams" in them.
I am printing on the  Anycubic Ultrabase.

[image: Seams in first layers]

Any other layer is fine.

Has anyone else experienced similar problems or an idea of how to debug this issue?

The picture is of PLA (BQ Easy Black) printed at 215 °C on the Ultrabase.
The the same issue with BQ Easy PLA red, turquoise and white (205 °C), Zaper PETG Brown 230 °C and HobbyKing translucent ABS Red (245 °C).

Changing the nozzle did not change anything.

Comment: Normally, such patterns are caused by too close printing to the bed (nozzle to bed distance too small), but considering the not fully flattened out extrusion lines (on glass I get a mirror shine fully closed surface) this does not seem to be the reason; you could try to increase the gap a little, in Ultimaker Cura this is very easily done with the `Z Offset Setting` plugin. Add to your question where you print on, it looks as if the bed is not flat.

Comment: @0scar Finally came to testing it. you were correct. Leveling the printbed (with 0.25mm cardboard) and the bottom Layer looks like it shoult . Thank You!

Comment: I'll make it into a proper answer then! Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally, such patterns are caused by too close printing to the bed (nozzle to bed distance too small), but considering the not fully flattened out extrusion lines (on glass I get a mirror shine fully closed surface) this does not seem to be the reason; you could try to increase the gap a little, in Ultimaker Cura this is very easily done with the Z Offset Setting plugin. Alternatively, you could use a little thicker paper to calibrate the bed levelling.